# How to filter element from a List using Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, list, filter, java-8, java-stream

I have a simple Java 8 example using `filter()` operation.

When I try to filter, I'm getting an empty list.

```
class Per {
    String id;

    Per(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> allIds = new ArrayList<>();
        allIds.add("1");
        allIds.add("2");
        allIds.add("3");
        allIds.add("4");

        List<Per> unavailableItems = new ArrayList<>();
        unavailableItems.add(new Per("2"));
        unavailableItems.add(new Per("4"));

        List<Per> ids = unavailableItems.stream().filter(per -> !(allIds.contains(per.getId())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(ids);// why its returning empty value


    }
}
```

Why am getting an empty list?

Comment: The code filters ("keeps") all `Per`s, whose `id`s are not in `allIds`. The `Per`s we have have id `"2"` and `"4"`. Both are contained in `allIds`, so they are discarded, and an empty list is returned.

Comment: if i dont implement toString() also, i should get some object reference right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `filter` as:

"Should I **include** (filter) this item, yes or no"

So when your code does the following:

```
List<Per> ids = unavailableItems.stream().filter(per -> !(allIds.contains(per.getId())))
```

Then your code checking if it should remove the item `Per("2")`

And the logic is "if `allIds` has a `"2"`? then **no**, don't filter it, don't include it (that's the `!` in your code)

And indeed, you're not including it.

Then repeats with `Per("4")` and you don't include it either.

The result of not including the two elements is an empty lis.

I hope this helps to clarify it.

Probably you think "filter" means, "filter out" or "exclude" but is the opposite.

It seems to me that you're trying to do the opposite, filter from `allIds` those elements that are in `unavailableItems`

In that case:

```
    List<String> allAvailable = allIds.stream().filter( id -> {
        for (Per p : unavailableItems) {
          if ( p.getId().equals(id)) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true;

    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(allAvailable);
```

Does exactly what you need and prints:

```
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an empty list because operation [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) will retain in the stream only elements that match the given predicate.

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match
> the given predicate.

Since all values that have in the source list are present in the `allIds` list predicate always returns `false`.

If you want to retain only elements that exist in the `allIds` list, change your predicate to:

```
filter(per -> allIds.contains(per.getId()))
```

To reduce time complexity of `contains()` checks, you might also make `allIds` to be `HashSet`.

---

If you want to do the opposite check - find a list of available `id`s (`id`s from `allIds` list that are not present in the `unavailableItems`) you can do it like this:

```
List<String> availableId = allIds.stream()
    .filter(id -> unavailableItems.stream()
                                  .noneMatch(pers -> pers.getId() == id))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And if that is what you're trying to achieve, my suggestion is to improve the code above by generating a `Map<String, Per>` - *person by id* based on the `availableId` list. And check whether the `id` is not present in the map instead of iterating over the whole `availableId` list.

```
Map<String, Per> personById = unavailableItems.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Per::getId, Function.identity()));
    
List<String> availableId = allIds.stream()
    .filter(id -> !personById.containsKey(id))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @shree But if you are checking a list of `2, 4` against the list of `1,2,3,4`. There's no value in the first list that are not contained in the second. Do you agree? Maybe you need values from `allIds` (`1,2,3,4`) that are not exist in the first list? In this case, you need to create a stream over `allIds` list.

Comment: @shree You mean how to obtain the `id`s from `allIds` list that are not present in the `unavailableItems` list, right? Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you have a not sign in front of your filter condition:

```java
!(allIds.contains(per.getId()))
```

So instead of filtering for items that are inside the list you are filter for items that are not inside the list. You unavailibleItems list only contains items with a matching item in the allIds list which means this condition is never going to be true. However if you removed the not sign it would work or if you added items into the unavailibleItems list that did not have a matching value in the allId's list it would work.

Comment: how to achieve with !contains? cant we do?